# RegistrationException - "does not have a strong name"

Tags: .net

I'm referencing a .NET DLL (which in turn references a lot of legacy COM DLLs) which is NOT strongly named.  I'm referencing this from an NUnit project, which is also not signed.

However when running and trying to instantiate a class, I receive the error message:

RegistrationException: The class XXX does not have a strong name.

Why would this be?

Note that I'm not asking HOW to sign the assembly (although that doesn't seem to work either) but rather WHY I'm being forced to sign it?

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: This question requires the StackTrace of the exception.